# When to shut down the Dio client in Flutter's Dio package?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Dio has a method `void close()` which shuts down the Dio client when called. The question I have is: **when should I call this method?**

The options obvious to me are:

- Call it after every "transaction of requests" is processed(most of the cases it would be **calling it after every request** I make in the REST API since most of the transactions are composed of a single request.)
- Never call it and leave the Dio client open all the time?

Would the second option become a problem because of leaving the connection open all the time?

Would the first option create considerable performance problems regarding the speed the requests are processed?

Answer (score -3):

You can close it in *dispose()* method in the top widget of your widget tree. This will close the dio once the app is closed.

Comment: This could only be done if there is a single instance of Dio open for the duration of the app's life, and unless the app is _constantly_ making HTTP calls, this would be considered bad practice.

Comment: Using dio for a single network call would be a bad practice.

Comment: Not really. It may be overkill, but there's nothing wrong with wanting a simpler way than using a raw `HttpClient` to make a simple API call. But I digress, that's beside the point.